# Intepreting linear regression

Tags: regression

favorite
In labour economics, the return to education denotes the response of the wage of an individual to an increase in individual’s education. It is estimated with a linear regression model:

$w_i= B_0 + B_1e_i +\epsilon_i$

where $w_i$ is the individual i’s wage (in dollars), $e_i$ is the individual i’s amount of years in education (in years), and $\epsilon_i$ is the noise. Let us assume the coefficient $B_0$ is estimated to be 13000 and the coefficient $B_1$ is estimated to be 1500.

What is $\epsilon_i$?

Comment: Didn't you already define it as the noise? It's unclear what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: Are you looking for the value of $e_i$? I.e. $e_i=w_i-B_0-B_1e_i$

Comment: Sorry, typo in my earlier comment. I meant $\epsilon_i=w_i-B_0-B_1e_i$

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, $\epsilon_i$ is the difference between an individual $i$'s actual wage and your model's prediction for $i$'s wage.

For example, let's assume that in the data, individual $i$ has $e_i = 12$ years of education and a wage of $w_i = 32{,}250$. Then the model prediction for $i$'s wage (given the coefficients you listed) is $13{,}000 + 1{,}500*12 = 31{,}000$. But we observed that $i$'s actual wage is $32{,}250$. Then $\epsilon_i = 32{,}250 - 31{,}000 = 1{,}250$. This is just a concrete example of the formula in @roundsquare's comment.

The $\epsilon_i$ are illustrated with fake data in the plot below. (The `R` code to create the plot is just below the plot.) We fit the model $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i$. In the plot, the points are the data, the line is the regression fit (where the function is $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$) and the red vertical lines are the $\epsilon_i$ (the difference between the regression line and the actual data), which are known as the residuals. The regression line is the particular line that minimizes $\Sigma{\epsilon_i^2}$ (the sum of the squared residuals).

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)

# Fake data
set.seed(491)
x = runif(50, 0, 100)
y = 2*x + 5 + rnorm(50,0,20)

# Combine x, y into a data frame
dat = data.frame(x,y)

# Fit regression model
m1 = lm(y ~ x, data=dat)

# Get predictions for regression model
dat$ypred = predict(m1)

ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, size=0.7) +
  geom_segment(aes(yend=ypred, xend=x), colour="red") +
  geom_point(pch=21, fill=hcl(240,100,55)) +
  theme_bw()
```

In R, you can extract all of the $\epsilon_i$ from the regression model `m1` above by running `resid(m1)` or `dat$y - predict(m1)`.

Comment: You appear not to distinguish between the model and its *estimates.*  By confusing the two, **you have incorrectly characterized the $\epsilon_i$.**  In your code, try storing the values of `rnorm(50,0,20)` used to compute `y` (those are the $\epsilon_i$) and compare them to `resid(m1)` (which is what your plot iillustrates): they will not agree.

Comment: @whuber, I'm not sure I understand your comment. The `rnorm(50,0,20)` was just to create some random noise in the fake data. I could have done `runif(50,-5,5)` or `c(1.2,-0.5,-10.2,...,0,3.2,0.72)`, etc. But don't the $\epsilon_i$ always represent the difference between the actual $y$ in the data and the model prediction for $y$ (which would be $\hat{y}$, but I was trying to avoid notation creep)? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Yes: it's important to maintain a sharp distinction between the *true* values in the model and the values that are *estimated* from data.  Your answer describes estimates, but the $\epsilon_i$ are intended to be true values.